# How to obtain , record and duration of app usage in minutes , seconds or hours

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have block of code that allows me to retreive all the apps/services running on my android device including the app that I
      am building. I am not entirely sure if I am on the right path butbecause I am debugging on android 4.3  I would like to use `ActivityManager.RunningService.activeSince`
      (per service/app) and subtract it from `SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();` which I understand is total milliseconds since reboot . So for example
      if the device was rebboted at 10am and whatsapp was started at 10:15 and the current time is 1030 I want to be able to use these values 
      to get an a close estimate of the amount spent on whatsapp. I have a feeling that this is not the most elegant way to achieve this and I am therefore very open to 
      any advice. This my code below thus far . For now I am using android 4.3

```
 ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager)this.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
         List<ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo> services = am.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
         for (ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo info : services) {
           cal.setTimeInMillis(currentMillis-info.activeSince);

            long millisSinceBoot = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
            long appStartTime =  info.activeSince;
            long appDuration =    appStartTime - millisSinceBoot ;
            //long time = ((millisSinceBoot - values.get(position).activeSince)/1000);
            //long time = ((millisSinceBoot - currentMillis-info.activeSince)/1000);
            //Log.i("HRHHRHRHRHR", "%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%"+time);
            //String time1 = String.valueOf(time);

            int seconds = (int) (appDuration / 1000) % 60 ;
            int minutes = (int) ((appDuration / (1000*60)) % 60);
            int hours   = (int) ((appDuration / (1000*60*60)) % 24);
            String time11 = hours+":"+minutes+":"+seconds;
            Log.i("Time", "Secs:- " + seconds + " " + "Mins:- " + minutes + " " + "Hours:- " + hours);
            Log.i(TAG, String.format("Process %s with component %s has been running since %s (%d milliseconds)",
                    info.process, info.service.getClassName(), cal.getTime().toString(), info.activeSince  ));
         }
```

Comment: @Jared Rummler    This my code  thus far